# Compare two DateTime Objects and get a DateTime Object back (Joda Time)

Tags: time, jodatime

I am using the joda Time Library for android and I am trying to get a DateTime Object only with compared hour and minute from two other DateTime Objects.

So I have :

```
DateTime start = new DateTime().withTime(startHour,startminute,0,0);
DateTime finish = new DateTime().withTime(finishHour, finishMinute, 0, 0);
```

So my solution was :

```
  int hoursbetween = Hours.hoursBetween(start, finish).getHours();
  int minutesbetween = Minutes.minutesBetween(start.withHourOfDay(0), finish.withHourOfDay(0)).getMinutes();
  DateTime between = new DateTime().withTime(hoursbetween,minutesbetween,0,0);
```

but this is ugly.Is there a better approach ?

thanks for your answers,
cheers pimato

Answer (score 2):

DateTime represents a point in time- with date parts, time parts and a time zone. The elapsed time between two DateTimes isn't really a DateTime, it's a Period (which both Hours and Minutes extend) or a Duration (when applied to a particular instant to make a fixed length of milliseconds)

```
    int startHour = 14;
    int startMinute = 12;
    int finishHour = 17;
    int finishMinute = 0;
    LocalTime start = new LocalTime(startHour, startMinute, 0, 0);
    LocalTime finish = new LocalTime(finishHour, finishMinute, 0, 0);
    Period period = Period.fieldDifference(start, finish);
    // PT3H-12M , generally equivalent to 2h48m

    DateTime newStartTime = DateTime.parse("2015-05-06T22:48:00+01:00");
    assertThat(newStartTime.plus(period), equalTo(DateTime.parse("2015-05-07T01:36:00+01:00")));
```

Comment: i forgot to tell you that I need to compare a Datetime from today (ex. 12 pm  with a DateTime from tomorrow (2 am)... And getting the exact hours and minutes out of the comparision ? how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Imagine how to calculate a night shift ? how would you do that ? Already thanks a lot for your help :)